# Fix letters with random shortcuts

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

When ever I press the <kbd>S</kbd> key it activates my 'screen Keyboard' in the 'Universal Access'. And when pressing <kbd>L</kbd> it opens Gnome Help.

This is a very weird bug and super annoying as I need to copy and paste 'S' and 'L' to type.

I have tried reboot.

<del>This happened after i did a:</del>

<del>`sudo apt-get purge cozy*`</del>

<del>As I didn't use it and never really did set up [cozy.io](https://cozy.io/en/) 

I'm not sure it has anything to do with cozy, but it happened sometime after that.</del>

<del>Anyone know where this setting could come from? 

I have tried looking at my keyboard shortcuts, and can't find it there. I also tried to just override it by making a new shortcut and set it to <kbd>S</kbd>, but that' not possible. Where I just get this message: ***The chortcut "S" cannot be ued because it will become impossible to type using this key.***</del>

**UPDATE:**

<del>I think it could have something to do with this. I tried to download this torrent: [Serie episode magnet link](http://magnet:?xt=urn:btih:72634d5388b73681c3a90eba8be4f74185f68296&dn=Silicon%20Valley%20S03E01%202015%20HDTV%20x264%20-%20BLOW&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969)

And I can see now that I got a .wmv file, as where I should get a .mkv file. I tried to open the file both with vlc and totem.</del>

**UPDATE:**

This seemed to happen because of a bug in Gnome 3.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Had The Same Problem**

Steps to Resolve the Issue;

In gnome settings - click on the keyboard option -- then  click on Universal Access -- then change the corresponding setting by clicking on (I.e. Turn On- Screen Keyboard on / off) and type a new short cut action I.e. -- **Alt+t** or **Alt+s** -- etc to avoid the short cut cant be used error message, this should work. I used the Alt key before a letter but its entirely up to you what you use before the letter key.

This will change the short cut and resolve the issue for the -- S -- key, also for the -- L -- key, you need to go to -- launchers -- and click on --launch help browser -- and repeat the steps choosing a short cut of your choice.

**Update!**

Make sure any short cut that says **Disabled** in Universal Access is changed with a different short cut -- **Alt+r** -- etc as the same happened to me and I had to change all disabled shot cuts, then reboot system.

Comment: This worked for the 'L' key, but not the 'S' key

Comment: Make sure any short cut that says Disabled in Universal Access is changed with a different short cut -- Alt+r -- etc as the same happened to me and I had to change all disabled shot cuts, then reboot system.

Comment: It worked! If I wanted to send a bug report on this, do you have any idea why it's happening and what is actually causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem yesterday, but it seems it was a bug introduced by package updates, today a bunch of gnome-shell updates came in and the problems were solved. Do you use the Gnome staging PPA? Actually I'm using it to try out Gnome 3.20 apps, but it's a **staging** ppa and therefore not marked as stable. Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and your problems should be solved with the *l* key, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the keybindings, that helped me because i had the same problem after some updates in 16.04 TLS and gnome 3.20.1 something

use

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.metacity.keybindings
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.mutter.keybindings
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.shell.keybindings
```

Try this I hope this fixes your problem.

Also you can see all your keybinding by simply running

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep keybindings
```